# Export back up copy of VM in Azure

Tags: backup, azure, virtual-machines

I have set up a linux VM running Ubuntu 16 using resource manager and image from the marketplace. I use only SSE encryption since I do not need extra data drive, and OS manged disk uses SSE encryption by default. I have enebaled every-day back up of the whole VM in Azure.

I would like to ask following questions regarding the VM:

1. Is it possible to export a backup copy of the VM from azure? If yes,
   can the copy be restored outside of the azure using a third-party
   tool? If yes, how?
2. Can the backup copy be restored on different
   azure account? If yes, how can I provide access to the backup copy
   to user with the different account? By different account I mean
   completely different user from other company...
3. If there is a sudden outage in the region where the VM is placed, what are my
   options to keep the VM running and enable users to use it without
   any notice? Should I use for it Disaster recovery available from VM
   detail? If yes, does it switch location automatically or there are
   some actions required once the outage happen?

I read all the docs but still can not find satisfying answers for my questions, so I might be just missing something. Thanks for any information!

Comment: For the copy of backup, you can take a look at [AzCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/move-data-to-azure-blob-using-azcopy), and if you want to use the VM without any notice when there is a sudden outage, you can follow the document [Availability Set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/manage-availability?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json).